# WTForms FileField AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'filename'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Flask + Sqlalchemy + WTForms

Code was working perfectly before, now with zero change I am receiving an error saying:

job = {"name": form.command.data.filename[:-3],
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'filename'

Which of course is very confusing as it has been working perfectly and very much had the attribute filename until this morning.

Below i've attached the form code and relevant view creation code, some info redacted for security.

Form Code:

```
class DkronJobForm(FlaskForm):

command = FileField("Python File", validators=[DataRequired()])
schedule = StringField('Schedule', validators=[DataRequired()]) 
timezone = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: Timezone.query.all(), get_label="name", default=lambda: Timezone.query.filter(Timezone.timezoneid == '418').one_or_none())
owner = StringField('Owner/Job Creator', validators=[DataRequired()])
owner_email = StringField("Owner's Email", validators=[Email()])
executor = StringField("Executor: (default=shell)", default="shell", validators=[DataRequired()])

#advanced options
exec_shell= BooleanField('Executor config: Shell (default = true)', default=True)
disable = BooleanField('Disable Job', default=False)
tags = StringField('Tags: Target nodes tags of this job', default=None)
retries = IntegerField('# of job retries if failed', default=0)
```

View creation code:

```
@admin.route('/dkron', methods=['GET','POST'])
def dkron_job():

global to_upload

check_BI_permission()

dkron = Dkron.query.all()
form=DkronJobForm()
null = None

if form.validate_on_submit():

    # save current and change to new working directory
    os.chdir("<path removed>")


    #creating json file from WTForm
    job = {"name": form.command.data.filename[:-3],
           "timezone": form.timezone.data.name,
           "shell": True, 
           "schedule": form.schedule.data,
           "environment_variables": null,
           "command":"",
           "owner": form.owner.data,
           "owner_email": form.owner_email.data,
           "disabled": form.disable.data,
           "tags": tags,
           "retries": form.retries.data,
           "dependent_jobs": null,
           "last_success":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
           "last_error":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
           "success_count":0,
           "error_count":0,
           "parent_job": "",
           "processors": null,
           "concurrency": "allow",
           "executor": form.executor.data,
           "executor_config": {"command": "<info removed>}}

    with open(form.command.data.filename[:-3] + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(job, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)

    # saving python script to correct location
    form.command.data.save('<path removed>'+form.command.data.filename)

    # uploading job to Dkron
    to_upload = form.command.data.filename[:-3] + '.json'

    cc="allow"


    new_job = Dkron(name=form.command.data.filename[:-3], 
                        timezone = form.timezone.data.name, 
                        schedule = form.schedule.data,
                        owner = form.owner.data,
                        owner_email = form.owner_email.data,
                        disabled = form.disable.data,
                        tags = form.tags.data,
                        retries = form.retries.data,
                        concurrency = cc,
                        executor = form.executor.data,
                        exec_command = form.command.data,
                        exec_shell = form.exec_shell.data)

    os.chdir("<path removed>")

    with open(form.command.data.filename[:-3]+".sh", "a+") as bash_file:
        bash_file.write("<code removed>+form.command.data.filename)

    os.chdir("<path removed>")

    try:    
        os.system("python JOBPOST_dkron.py "+ form.command.data.filename[:-3]+".json")
        db.session.merge(new_job)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('admin.dkron_job'))
    except:
        flash('Sorry an error occurred while attempting to commit the job.')
        return redirect(url_for('admin.dkron_job'))

return render_template('admin/dkron.html',form=form, dkron=dkron,
                       title='Dkron')
```

From personal research I see there was a solution some time ago that required form = Form(request.form) to become form = Form(), however as you can see that is not the issue here.

I am quite confused and any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you to take a look at [Filefield documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FileField) or even source code to see that in Filefield there would be no `filename` attribute, but actual sent file name would be in `field.data`, so `form.command.data` in your case.

P.S. Also, removing last 3 symbols is a bad way to get rid of file extension, use [stdlib os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) instead.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem and also thanks for the documentation links. splitext was exactly what i needed.